# AVAudioEngine with Today Extension

Tags: ios, swift, today-extension, avaudioengine, sfspeechrecognizer

Hello I want to add the Speech framework to an iOS 10 Today Extension.

I try to use SpeakToMe sample https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/SpeakToMe/Introduction/Intro.html to record audio with AVAudioEngine.

But I get an exception when I try to start the audio engine

```
try audioEngine.start()

2016-10-04 22:21:24.658964 VoiceReco[4225:1230467] [aurioc] 1316: AUIOClient_StartIO failed (561145187)
2016-10-04 22:21:24.663743 VoiceReco[4225:1230467] [central] 54:   ERROR:    [0x1af158c40] >avae> AVAudioEngineGraph.mm:1175: Start: error 561145187
```

The sample code from apple works fine if I use the normal view controller without my extension. Does anyone know a workaround for this?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't record audio in an extension.
[Check here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1872/_index.html)